# Regular expression for a phrase like zzz abc_2006073122

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression for the following please

```
zzz abc_2006073122

zzz abc_def_2006073122

zzz abc_def_ghi_2006073122
```

I need to get the first 8 digits of the date (20060731) but i may have several _ parts before that so not quite sure what expression will get me what i need.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about obtaining a solution without demonstrating sufficient research/effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string str = @"zzz abc_def_ghi_2006073122";
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z_ ]*_(?<someNamedGroup>\d{8})");
        var match = reg.Match(str);
        var result = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Regex is something like:

`([0-9]{8})(?:[0-9]{2})$`

Meaning: anchored to the end of the string, 8 digits to "take", 2 digits to ignore.

If you can't use the end of the line as anchor, you can try this:

`(?:_)([0-9]{8})(?:[0-9]{2})`

Meaning: a `_` followed by 10 digits. Only 8 of these digits will be captured.

Comment: Thanks, there is more unknown text on the end of my strings so the dollar probably does not help

Comment: @Mark then you should write it in the example.